# How to dynamically access value of a property in Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, properties

I have the following Javascript object:-

```
var attributes = {
  entityData: {
    Party: 12
  },
  entityType: "Party"
};
```

Now I want to fetch dynamically the Party property value something like below. How can I do this?

```
alert(attributes.entityData.{attributes.entityType});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this perhaps:

```js
var attributes = {
    entityData: {
    Party: 12
  },
  entityType: "Party"
};

console.log(attributes.entityData[attributes['entityType']]);
```

Use square braces instead of curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

whenever you need to access dynamic property you have to use square bracket for accessing property .

 **Syntax: object[propery]**

```js
var attributes = {
    entityData: {
    Party: 12
  },
  entityType: "Party"
};

alert(attributes.entityData[attributes.entityType]);
```

```
alert(attributes.entityData[attributes.entityType]);
```