# How to get an Object by name from Datastructure in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following Datastructur in Javascript

```
  data: {…}
        0_0: {…}
            file: “xy.jpg”
            height: 256
            width: 256
            <prototype>: Object { … }
        0_256: {…}
            file: "xx.jpg"
            height: 256
            width: 256
        <prototype>: Object { … }
```

How can I get the data from "0_256"?

Comment: Have you tried `whateverVariableNameYouHave.data['0_256']`?

Comment: This syntax seems too weird for javascript.

Comment: @Ivan `0_0` is beautiful though :)

Comment: Already asked many time please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51607527/4225796

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `data['0_256']`:

```js
var data = {
    '0_0': {
          file: "xy.jpg",
          height: 256,
          width: 256
     },
    '0_256': {
          file: "xx.jpg",
          height: 256,
          width: 256
    }
};
console.log(data['0_256']);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try "data['0_256']"

```
`console.log(data['0_256'])`
```

```js
var   data = { 
        "0_0" :{
            file: "xy.jpg",
            height: 256,
            width: 256
            },
        "0_256":{
            file: "xx.jpg",
            height: 256,
            width: 256
            }
          }
console.log(data['0_256']);
```